# Error using a function of jpl API when running in a phone with android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, prolog, android-library, jpl

I am linking a game developed in prolog to an android app in android studio whith jpl (http://jpl7.org/740/doc/index.html) and an error occurs when I use a function of the library jpl7.

[The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSGiU.png)

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.android.sevens, PID: 25397
              java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.sevens-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.sevens-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.sevens-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.sevens-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.sevens-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.sevens-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.sevens-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.sevens-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.sevens-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.sevens-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.sevens-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.sevens-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.android.sevens-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.example.android.sevens-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.example.android.sevens-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.example.android.sevens-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.example.android.sevens-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.example.android.sevens-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.example.android.sevens-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.example.android.sevens-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.example.android.sevens-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.example.android.sevens-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.example.android.sevens-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.example.android.sevens-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.example.android.sevens-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]] couldn't find "libjpl.so"
                  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:972)
                  at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1530)
                  at org.jpl7.JPL.loadNativeLibrary(JPL.java:112)
                  at org.jpl7.fli.Prolog.<clinit>(Prolog.java:70)
                  at org.jpl7.fli.Prolog.thread_self(Native Method)
                  at org.jpl7.Query.open(Query.java:300)
                  at org.jpl7.Util.textToTerm(Util.java:127)
                  at org.jpl7.Query.<init>(Query.java:185)
                  at com.example.android.sevens.Main2Activity.play(Main2Activity.java:29)
                  at com.example.android.sevens.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:23)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6847)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2649)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2757)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1504)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6237)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

the code:

```
 1.package com.example.android.sevens;
 2.
 3.import android.net.Uri;
 4.import android.os.Bundle;
 5.import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 6.import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
 7.import android.widget.TextView;
 8.
 9.import org.jpl7.Query;
10.import org.jpl7.Term;
11.
12.import java.util.Map;
13.
14.public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
15.
16.    @Override
17.    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
18.        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
19.        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
20.        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
21.        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
22.
23.        play();
24.    }
25.
26.    public void play(){
27.        Map<String, Term> solution;
28.
29.        Query q = new Query("member(2,[1,2,3])");
30.        q.hasSolution();
           (...)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please paste your error message into the question as text, rather than as an image. People will never find the image when searching.

Comment: JPL needs a runnable swipl instance. It would be **really** nice to have SWI-Prolog running on Android. But - alas - we are not there, and will not in foreseeable future